# Batch File - move duplicate files

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I'm having a headache with this for loop in a batch file.

Basically, I am searchign through an archive folder to see if a file has already been processed. If so, then move the file to a duplicates folder. I've set the date variables above in the script and they work fine:

```
 for %%f in (%toLoadLocation%\*.*) DO (
 if exist %archiveLocation%\%%~nxf (
 IF NOT EXIST "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates" mkdir "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates"
 IF NOT EXIST "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%" mkdir "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%"
 IF NOT EXIST "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%\%localMM%" mkdir "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%\%localMM%"
 copy %%f "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%\%localMM%"
 echo %localDate% %localTime%       Duplicate claims file: %%f File moved to archive     >> "%logLocation%\Error.log"
 )
```

Am I doing something dumb here? I don't get an error, the script just bombs out when runnign this (I've a pause command before and after this hoping to catch a message, but nothing)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use quotes on these 2 lines:

```
if exist "%archiveLocation%\%%~nxf" (
```

and

```
copy "%%f" "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%\%localMM%"
```

Comment: I'm still crashing out with quotes around everything. I'm not misusing the brackets am I?

Comment: Never mind, I was missing an extrac closing bracket - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for %%f in ("%toLoadLocation%\*.*") DO if exist "%archiveLocation%\%%~nxf" (
    IF NOT EXIST "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates" mkdir "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates"
    IF NOT EXIST "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%" mkdir "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%"
    IF NOT EXIST "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%\%localMM%" mkdir "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%\%localMM%"
    copy "%%~f" "%archiveLocation%\Duplicates\%localYYYY%\%localMM%"
    echo %localDate% %localTime%        Duplicate claims file: %%f File moved to archive     >> "%logLocation%\Error.log"
)
```